# Why i += i + a[i++] + a[i++] + a[i++] results in 8?

Tags: java, increment, operator-precedence

I am totally lost why I get these results:

```
    int i = 1;

    int[] a = new int[6];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    a[2] = 2;
    a[3] = 3;
    a[4] = 4;
    a[5] = 5;

    i += i + a[i++] + a[i++]; 
   //i is 5

   i = 1;

   i += i + a[i++] + a[i++] + a[i++];
   // i is 8
```

I (wrongly) thought that there are these options:

1. `i = i(=1) + a[i++]` + etc - meaning that i = 1 is cached and not
   changed then. Expression evaluation order is exactly from left to
   right, I guess (?!).
2. i is increased, which results (for first example) in `i = i(=3) + a[1] + a[2]` now i = 3 and written to leftmost i
3. value from rightmost a[THIS_VALUE] is substituted into leftmost i, and last increment is never made.

But actual results leave me with no clue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i += i + a[i++] + a[i++];
```

adds the original value of i to the value of the expression `i + a[i++] + a[i++]` and assigns the result to `i`.

It's equivalent to

```
i = i + i + a[i++] + a[i++];
    1 + 1 + a[1]   + a[2]    = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 5
```

Then you assign 1 to `i` and calculate:

```
i += i + a[i++] + a[i++] + a[i++];
```

which is equivalent to

```
i = i + i + a[i++] + a[i++] + a[i++];
    1 + 1 + a[1]   + a[2]   + a[3] = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 8
```

The important thing to note is that each `a[i++]` increments `i`, but accesses the element of `a` at the index of the previous value of `i` (i.e. the value prior to the increment).

Therefore the first `a[i++]` returns `a[1]` (even though `i` is incremented to 2), the second `a[i++]` returns `a[2]` (even though `i` is incremented to `3`) and the third `a[i++]` returns `a[3]` (even though `i` is incremented to `4`).

Comment: I think to clear the OP's source of confusion, it should be stated that the increments (i++) have no effect on the value of i in sub-expressions on the left. I.e. in `i + a[i++]` the fact that `i` gets incremented has no effect on the value of `i` on the left of the `+` sign.

Answer (score 1):

This important to notice differences between i++ and ++i, when you use i++ it use i value to calculate the operation and then increment i, but when you are using ++i it increment i and the calculate the operation.

it also worth mentioning that i+=X is equal to i = i + X.

So

```
i += i + a[i++] + a[i++];
```

is equal to

```
i = i + i + a[i++] + a[i++]
```

for i = 1 it is

```
i = 1 + 1 + a[1] + a[2]
```

which with your initialisation it will be :

```
i = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2
```

and thats how you get i = 5. and same for next line.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy acutally, your using post increment. Post increment increments the value after the expression was executed, versus pre which increments before the expression is executed. So `i += i + a[i++] + a[i++] + a[i++];`, is 1 += 1 + 1 + 2 + 3, the first access, uses 1, then increment, next access uses two then increment then last access uses three.